# Logic for Up- and Down Voting System to Avoid Multiple Voting of an Item by a User in PHP Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am thinking about what is the most resource efficient logic for an up and down voting system. A user can vote a post and its comments up- and down. For this I have implemented a polymorphic relationship between the models vote, post and comment.

**My problem is:** I want to list all posts with the title and the votes on a post overview page. The up and down vote buttons can be used. As soon as a (logged in) user votes for a post, it should be increased or decrease by 1. The button will be highlighted so that the user can see how he has already voted for this post. If he clicks the same button again, the vote should be undone.

**My approach**
`$posts = Post::with('votes')->get();`
Gives me posts with the relation votes and the corresponding votes. Now I could iterate the vote collection in the blade for each individual post and catch via the user id whether he has already voted.

**Question(s)**
My goal is actually a list only with the posts where I add fields in the backend like hasVoted, voteDirection. But only for the logged in user.  1. that I don't have to do a nested iteration and 2. that I don't have unnecessary overhead (votes from other users).

```php
// Vote Model
class Vote extends Model
{
    public function voteable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

// Post Model
class Post extends Model
{
    public function publisher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'publisher_id', 'id');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }

    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Vote::class, 'voteable');
    }
}

// User Model
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function votes() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vote::class);
    }    
}
// Comment Model
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Vote::class, 'voteable');
    }    
}
```

```php
// Vote migration
Schema::create('votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->morphs('voteable');
    $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->integer('vote')->default(1);    
    $table->timestamps();
});

// Post migration
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->integer('publisher_id'); // user
   $table->string('slug');
   $table->string('title');  
   $table->string('votes')->default(json_encode(['up' => 0, 'down' => 0]));
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this issue simply with a component of 2 radio buttons. Then via names attach the values and then there is no way that one user has voted 2 times on the same post. I hope this helps you.

Comment: In any case, this is an interesting approach to solving this on the front end. Thanks for that! I use an api for this, so you could work around this solution and use it to submit multiple votes, which I don't want to do. So I'm more interested in the backend. How can I enrich every single post in the post collection with data like userHasVoted and userVoteDirection. In summary, how can I extract fields from the relation of a post to attach them to the post as new fields and delete the relation again?

Comment: @MaxPattern Oh sorry, didn't see it is an API there :D So, in that case, when you take the data for each post, I'd make an empty array for example `$alreadyVoted`, and store a `user_id` in there. And every time loop goes off I would first check if `user_id` exists in my array, if it does, go to the next value, and if not, proceed to the store method. For checking, if something exists in the array I would use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm really happy to give you an upvote for that. But that's not what I'm looking for and asked. I will probably loop the posts in the backend and create a new collection with the new fields. I don't know why but I think Laravel can do that. Laravel is also just great.

Comment: I will give you two upvotes in other answers of yours if it's ok with you?

Comment: @MaxPattern sure, if I gave an idea or something go for it :D