# Is it possible to read out relations of a model and attach them to the parent model?

Tags: laravel

I have two models in my Laravel project (Post, Vote). Post and Vote have a relation to each other. When I get a collection of the post together with votes, I want to modify the response object beforehand and delete the relation again.

**Here are my 3 steps:**

1. `$postsWithRelation = Post::with('votes')->get();`

```
[
  [
    id: int,
    title: string,
    votes: [
      [
        id: int,
        voteDirection: string <up || down>
      ],
    ]
  ],
]
```

2. **Modify:** ???
3. **Response:** Here I only want to return the modified post entity and not the relation:

```
id: int,
title: string,
userHasVoted: bool <true || false>
userVoteDirection: string <up || down>
```

**Question:** How can I perform step 2. The best would be to use Laravel's own functions if Laravel can do it. Thanks for your time!

#### Update

Thanks to Daniel for his good answer. It would work like this. However, I wonder if it could be optimised. Is calling the relation a lazy load in the map closure? Because an output of the parameter Post of the function shows me only the Post and no relation to Vote. Although I have eagerly loaded the query before.

```
$postsWithRelation = Post::with('votesByUser')->get();
$posts = $postsWithRelation->map(function(Post $post) {
    return [
        'id' => $post->id,
        'title' => $post->title,
        'userHasVoted' => count($post->votesByUser) ? true : false, 
        'userVoteDirection' => $post->votesByUser[0]->vote ?? null,
    ];
}); 

// I added this method to my Post Model too

public function votesByUser()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Vote::class, 'voteable')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of collections,

```php
$postsWithRelation = Post::with('votes')->get();
$posts = $postsWithRelation->map(function(Post $post) use ($user) {
  return [
    'id' => $post->id,
    'title' => $post->title,
    'userHasVoted' => ..., // here you need to check if user has voted
    'userVoteDirection' => ..., // and determine his vote direction
  ];
});
```

Comment: Thx Daniel! I am glad that another dev would do the same. That is an approach I have already thought of :-) But I had assumed that it might be possible to do this in step one. Maybe as a closure of the with() function. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Using Closure inside `with`, you can modify Query Builder for querying vote relation. How looks like Vote model?

Comment: I posted my models already in an other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74873057/logic-for-up-and-down-voting-system-to-avoid-multiple-voting-of-an-item-by-a-us

Comment: Hi Daniel I updated my question with your answer! Maybe you can take a look? Because I think maybe this approach is expensive? Bardzo dzienkuje za twoj czas! Pozdrawjam